# merging the returned data from different methods in a single model containing in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model

I am creating a web app using `asp.net MVC` on my `ActionResult` method I have a model named as `UserProfile` which consist of user details,

now I am calling 2 methods from here one for user's basic information, and second for licence information

```
UserProfile model = GetUserInformationInList(objUser.GetData());// for basic info
```

in this `UserProfile model` I will get user `firstname, lastname, dob.`etc

```
UserProfile configFields = GetUserLicense();// for license info
```

in this `UserProfile configFields` I will get user `licenseId, licenseName.`etc

now I want to merge the data `model` and `configFields`

I can merge the data like the below

```
UserProfile data = new UserProfile(){
        firstname = model.firstname,
        licenseName = configFields.licenseName
};
```

but is there any better way of merging the data into the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter how you merge the data after already loading it into the memory, it will not make much of a difference. But if possible try to populate the data in time of retrieval from database. It will use much less memory and your application will be much faster.

If you are using separate APIs do get the data from two different source, I have to surrender there!

Happy coding!